# Overriden event not being called in user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with a `TextBox` on it:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public new event CancelEventHandler Validating
    {
        add
        {
            txt.Validating += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            txt.Validating -= value;
        }
    }

    public new string Text
    {
        get => txt.Text;
        set => txt.Text = value;
    }
}
```

I place the control and an `ErrorProvider` on a form and do the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        SetErrorEvents(myControl1);
    }

    private void SetErrorEvents(object control)
    {
        (control as Control).Validating += ValidationEvent;
    }

    private void ValidationEvent(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Control)sender;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text))
            errorProvider1.SetError(control, "error");
        else
            errorProvider1.SetError(control, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

When setting the delegate for the my control's `Validating` event, it's setting the delegate for the `UserControl` itself and not being overriden so that the event of the `TextBox` will be set.

Shouldn't the above work as is? What am I missing?

Comment: It's not overriden, it's new.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I can only set new as the event is not virtual. If I do `(control as MyControl).Validating += ValidationEvent;` it works but I can't do that because it's a method which accepts other types of controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not overriden, it's been shadowed or hidden by `new` keyword. You haven't subscribed to the new event, you have subscribed for the base class event. It's basically how [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) works.

- If you want to raise the `Validating` event of the user control when a child control is validating, handle `Validating` event of the child control and call `OnValidating` method of the user control.
- If you want to override the `Validating` event override `OnValidating` method.
- If you want to change the sender of `Validating` event, you need to change the way that `Validating` event has been invoked. To do so, you need to use reflection and find the event and directly invoke it yourself.

**Example - Raising Validating event of UserControl when Child control is validating**

If you like to raise `Validating` event of your control when the child text box is validating, handle `Validating` event of the child control and call ``

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txt.Validating += (obj, args) => OnValidating(args);
}
```

**Example - Override Validating Event**

```
protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
{       
    // Add custom code here.       
    base.OnValidating(e);
}
```

**Example - Raising `Validating` event manually without calling `base.OnValidating`**

If for some reason you don't want to call `base.OnValidating`, while its responsibility is basically raising the `Validating` event, you can find the event and invoke it directly:

```
protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
{  
    var f = typeof(Control).GetField("EventValidating",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    var validating = (CancelEventHandler)Events[f.GetValue(this)];
    validating?.Invoke(this, e); 
}
```

Doing so, for example you can set another sender like the child control, instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. However, this doesn't solve my problem. I have to set the `Validating` delegate, and instead of setting the one for the `UserControl` itself and I need set that of its `TextBox`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I believe the answer contains all the information which you need to solve the problem. For example if you want `ValidationEvent` receive `txt` as `sender` and also the error provider show the error near the `txt` rather than the user control, it's enough to mix example 1 and example 3 and in the example 3 raise the event using `validating?.Invoke(txt, e);` This way you can use your general code to subscribe the event. It always raise the event when `txt` is validating and the sender is `txt`, while you subscribed to usercontrol'a validating event.

Answer (score 1):

Define this interface:

```
public interface IMyControl
{
    event CancelEventHandler Validating;
}
```

Apply the interface to your customized controls:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl, IMyControl
{
    ...
}
```

In your `Form` class, update `SetErrorEvents()` so it cast to `IMyControl` instead:

```
...
private void SetErrorEvents(object control)
{
    (control as IMyControl).Validating += ValidationEvent;
}
...
```

Comment: I need to keep this methed "generic" as it handles different types of controls.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, no problem, please check my updated answer; you will need to apply that interface to the controls where you need that behavior.